# Why is the psframe not including the right end?

Tags: backgrounds, posters

I am working on a poster, the code is given below, but how do I make the blue box even on both sides? Why is it not including the right end? It's the first time I'm doing a poster and psframe, so please tell me where the mistake in the code is (I'm sure its in the psframe line though)

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}


\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}


\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                Poster                        %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{poster}{
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
}{
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pcolumn                       %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
}{
  \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Begin of Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\newrgbcolor{whiteblue}{0.90588 0.96470 0.99215}
\newrgbcolor{blue}{0 0.39215 0.694117}
\newrgbcolor{orange}{0.96078 0.50196 0.14901}
\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{0.83137 0.964705 0.99215}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
%\background{1. 1. 1.}{1. 1. 1.}{0.5}
  \psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=blue,
  gradbegin=lightblue,gradmidpoint=1](0,0)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
\begin{poster}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Column 1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}
\large{
%Insert stuff here
}
\end{pcolumn}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Column 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}

\end{pcolumn}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Column 3
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}

\end{pcolumn}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loads of `%` missing from the ends of lines, these are generating white space in the output pushing your frame off the page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}


\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}


\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                Poster                        %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{poster}{%
  \begin{center}%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{center}%
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pcolumn                       %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}%
  \begin{center}%
}{%
  \end{center}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Begin of Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\newrgbcolor{whiteblue}{0.90588 0.96470 0.99215}
\newrgbcolor{blue}{0 0.39215 0.694117}
\newrgbcolor{orange}{0.96078 0.50196 0.14901}
\newrgbcolor{lightblue}{0.83137 0.964705 0.99215}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
%\background{1. 1. 1.}{1. 1. 1.}{0.5}
  \psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=blue,
  gradbegin=lightblue,gradmidpoint=1](0,0)(1\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
\begin{poster}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Column 1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}
\large
%Insert stuff here
\end{pcolumn}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Column 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}

\end{pcolumn}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Column 3
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}

\end{pcolumn}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found another way by compiling it to dvi, but this is much easier. Thanks!